# How far can one get using magento with no coding experience?

Tags: magento2, extensions, learn-magento, coding, learning

I've been searching since yesterday and can find no information on this question.

I'm planning an ecommerce store. At first I just want to keep it as simple as possible. I have 3 partners who are able-minded and can learn simple tasks as we go. So, the question is:

**How far can I get with Magento using tutorials and trusted extensions?**

Furthermore any recommended resources in tutorials or extensions would be highly appreciated.

Magento seems ideal for its security features and future-proofness. Also extensions are not as costly as other platforms. Once we grow enough to afford to hire coders, the sky is the limit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do Magento 2, it will be extremely difficult for non-developer to even set up a shop without background knowledge of all of the technologies (*ElasticSearch, MySQL, PHP, Redis, Varnish, NGINX, Docker*).

**Time on the market**

I would recommend to use Shopify as you can start a full functioning store in about an hour.

Shopify is stable, has a ton of plugins and is *secure without a developer*.

The more time you are on the market the better your chances are that you can succeed.

Also, it will allow you to concentrate on selling instead of building up a shop.

I have seen shop owners spend upwards of $200,000 without a single product sold - you want to prove your product can be sold as soon as possible to see if you business is viable.

**Magento 2**

Magento 2 is not made for small shops - its made for *medium* to *large* businesses (15-1000s employees).

Hosting services for Magento 2 are also very expensive. You will need at least a *4 core / 8 thread CPU* with *16GB of RAM* to even run a basic store.

If you absolutely want to go with Magento, use [OpenMage](https://www.openmage.org/) (an open source fork of Magento 1). It has low requirements (1GB RAM) and a ton of tutorials.

PS: I have been doing Magento development for 6 years and done general E-commerce for 11 years.